# Best way for terminating threads started by myself

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm currently building a jar which runs inside of a parent. My project starts quite a lot of Threads which all get terminated in about 20-200ms (however have a possibility for being active for much longer). These threads can be started at any time during the process's runtime. Parent process has the ability to stop/restart sub programs. How can I terminate all active threads that I've started?

I've thought of making a list of all threads however that would quickly get cluttered with terminated threads.

How should I go about this?

Comment: create atomic bool global variable, make each thread test this variable once in a while

Comment: Do the threads come to a natural end and are left hanging or do you wish to kill the thread after a period of time, no matter what they are doing?

Comment: Redesign so that you never need to try.

Comment: Are you aware of the Executors framework built into Java 5+?

Comment: Explain: “Parent process has the ability to stop/restart sub programs.“

Comment: Unfortunately the design is not up to me.

Comment: The parent process has the ability to stop and start sub processes (jars placed in a folder)

Comment: I'd like to kill the thread no matter what state their in

Comment: @SwordOfSouls 'Unfortunately the design is not up to me'...ah, I see.  Update your CV and mail it to the agencies.....